# Python ungzipping stream of bytes?

Tags: python, compression

Here is the situation:

- I get gzipped xml documents from Amazon S3

  ```
    import boto
    from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
    from boto.s3.key import Key
    conn = S3Connection('access Id', 'secret access key')
    b = conn.get_bucket('mydev.myorg')
    k = Key(b)
    k.key('documents/document.xml.gz')
  ```
- I read them in file as

  ```
    import gzip
    f = open('/tmp/p', 'w')
    k.get_file(f)
    f.close()
    r = gzip.open('/tmp/p', 'rb')
    file_content = r.read()
    r.close()
  ```

**Question**

How can I ungzip the streams directly and read the contents?

I do not want to create temp files, they don't look good.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`zlib` module](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) to decompress byte streams:

```
import zlib

def stream_gzip_decompress(stream):
    dec = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)  # offset 32 to skip the header
    for chunk in stream:
        rv = dec.decompress(chunk)
        if rv:
            yield rv
    if dec.unused_data:
        # decompress and yield the remainder
        yield dec.flush()
```

The offset of 32 signals to the `zlib` header that the gzip header is expected but skipped.

The S3 key object is an iterator, so you can do:

```
for data in stream_gzip_decompress(k):
    # do something with the decompressed data
```

Comment: Would this need a call to`dec.flush()` at the end to make sure to not miss any data?

Comment: @MichalCharemza: yes, that's a very good point. Add `if dec.unused_data: yield dec.flush()` to the end.

Answer (score 10):

I had to do the same thing and this is how I did it:

```
import gzip
f = StringIO.StringIO()
k.get_file(f)
f.seek(0) #This is crucial
gzf = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
file_content = gzf.read()
```

Comment: what is `k` here?

Answer (score 6):

For Python3x and boto3-

So I used BytesIO to read the compressed file into a buffer object, then I used zipfile to open the decompressed stream as uncompressed data and I was able to get the datum line by line.

```
import io
import zipfile
import boto3
import sys

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 'us-east-1')


def stream_zip_file():
    count = 0
    obj = s3.Object(
        bucket_name='MonkeyBusiness',
        key='/Daily/Business/Banana/{current-date}/banana.zip'
    )
    buffer = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read())
    print (buffer)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
    foo2 = z.open(z.infolist()[0])
    print(sys.getsizeof(foo2))
    line_counter = 0
    for _ in foo2:
        line_counter += 1
    print (line_counter)
    z.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream_zip_file()
```

Comment: I noticed that the memory consumption increases significantly when we do `buffer = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read())`. However `read(1024)` reading a certain portion of the data keeps the memory usage low!

Comment: `buffer = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read())` reads the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PIPE and read contents without downloading file

```
    import subprocess
    c = subprocess.Popen(['-c','zcat -c <gzip file name>'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for row in c.stdout:
      print row
```

In addition  "/dev/fd/" + str(c.stdout.fileno()) will provide you FIFO file name (Named pipe) which can be passed to other program.

Comment: but you would you pass to `zcat` the zipped bytes coming from S3 ?

Comment: `zcat` is not particularly portable, you'd better use `gunzip -c`

Comment: Shelling out to do this with all the overhead of process setup and the like is absolutely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I absolutely agree, CW.  But I love to see it offered.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way for gzip files:

```
import gzip
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='Bucket', key='file.gz')
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=obj.get()["Body"]) as file:
    for line_bytes in file:
        print(line_bytes)
```