# Unzip my_file.zip pulled from s3 using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to use `boto` to open a `.zip` file I have in `s3`. I am trying to work with the data directly, I want to avoid creating temporary files.

```
In [201]: import StringIO

In [202]: import boto

In [203]: conn = boto.connect_s3()

In [204]: my_bucket = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')

In [205]: my_list = [ele for ele in my_bucket.list('my_file.zip')]

In [206]: f = StringIO.StringIO()

In [207]: my_list[0].get_file(f)

In [208]: f.seek(0)
```

If the file was not zipped I would just use:

```
my_content = my_list[0].get_contents_as_string()
```

but since it is zipped, I am getting garbage.

[An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes) does what I want (I borrowed a bit of my attempt from it) using `gzip`, but I can't find anything using for `zip`. I tried using `zipfileZipFile`, but `read`, `extract` and `extractall` methods don't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into the python module gzip :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

you should be able to stringIO with gzip.
.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO

S3Conn = S3Connection() # assuming your .boto has been setup
Bucket = S3Conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')
my_list = [gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=(StringIO(ele.get_contents_as_string()))) for ele in Bucket.list()]
#for readability I pulled this out
for item in my_list:
    item.read()
```

for readability the list comprehension should probably be broken up - but I followed your original posting to compare.

Good luck!

Comment: i think that should be "from boto", not "from goto".