# Can I create a python iterable object from an AWS S3 key?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, key, iterable

I am trying to use a third-party utility that processes data from an iterable object e.g. a queue or a file. I need to push a bunch of AWS S3 files though this utility. Each one is a text file containing JSON messages, one complete message per line.

One approach would be to make a local copy of each file using  `key.get_contents_to_filename()`, then open the local file for reading and pass the file object to the utility, then delete the local copy when done. But I am trying to avoid downloading files locally and prefer instead to read directly from S3. Is it possible to create an iterable object from an S3 key directly?

Comment: You want to retrieve a text file from S3 and put the *bytes* in an iterable container for processing- without saving it to local storage? And you have multiple files to do this to?  Similar question, no answer yet, - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29086699/2823755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `key.get_contents_as_string` method that you could probably *load* into `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO`.

```
>>> import io
>>> bt = io.BytesIO('abc\ndef\nghi')
>>> st = io.StringIO(u'abc\ndef\nghi')
>>> for thing in st:
        print thing


abc

def

ghi
>>> for thing in bt:
        print thing


abc

def

ghi
>>>
```