# python - Unzip csv file from S3 (in memory) and then iterate it

Tags: python, amazon-s3, zip

I've got a zip file in S3 bucket called 'My_Bucket'. the file key is 'MY_FILE.ZIP'.
The extracted file name is 'MY_FILE_FULL_NAME.CSV'.
I would like to get the file from the S3 bucket, extract it and iterate it.
As the job will be done by Lambda function - I would like to extract the file **in memory** (stream).
I started to write the below:
    import zipfile
    import boto3
    import io

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket('My_Bucket')
obj = bucket.Object('YYY.zip')

with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
    tf.seek(0)

#How should I continue ???
```

I need the part from unzipping through opening the file, reading it line by line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086699/unzip-my-file-zip-pulled-from-s3-using-boto ?