# Limit memory use when extracting from zip archives in Python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, zip

I am extracting large files from zip in a python script like this:

```
import zipfile
import tempfile

tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/file.zip')
zf.extractall(tmpdir)
```

This works fine but for large files this consumes too much memory to run it on small servers.

Is there a way to control/limit how much memory this extraction uses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unzipping stream of bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes)