# Streaming decompression of S3 gzip source object to a S3 destination object using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, boto3

**Given a large `gzip` object in S3, what is a memory efficient (e.g. streaming) method in python3/boto3 to decompress the data and store the results back into another S3 object?**

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes) previously asked.  However, all of the answers use a methodology in which the contents of the gzip file are first read into memory (e.g. `ByteIO`).  These solutions are not viable for objects that are too big to fit in main memory.

For large S3 objects the contents need to be read, decompressed "on the fly", and then written to a different S3 object is some chunked fashion.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: In what way the approved answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes) does not solve your problem? If you are running Python 3 the for loop will behave as a generator, so the unzip will be streamed.

Comment: @Tim It needs to be tied into boto3 for S3 interface.

Comment: How much memory are you willing to use? For streaming transfer you will always need to use some memory, because the mulitpart upload API requires content checksums sent in the request *headers* for each part - you'll need a memory buffer at least in the ballpark of `part_size` * `n_concurrent_parts`. Is there any reason why you need to stream, rather than simply using a temporary file?

Comment: Boto3 handles this for you with meta.client.download_file. See answer.

Comment: @wim I'm not asking for 0 memory usage, but I am asking  that the memory  consumed not grow with the size of the file.  I suppose a temporary file could work, though it's highly inefficient.

Comment: You can buffer to disk but you'll have to be careful for the reader not to "catch up" to the writer and think it's done. I actually have code that does exactly this, backs up a db to disk while simultaneously uploading to s3. I've been meaning to open source for a year now...

Comment: @kurt Looking for this capability. Was it open sourced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use streaming methods with **boto / s3** but you have to define your own file-like objects AFAIK.
Luckily there's [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) which handles that for you; it also supports *GCS, Azure, HDFS, SFTP* and others.
Here's an example using a large [sample](http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/) of sales data:

```py
import boto3
from smart_open import open

session = boto3.Session()  # you need to set auth credentials here if you don't have them set in your environment
chunk_size = 1024 * 1024  # 1 MB
f_in = open("s3://mybucket/2m_sales_records.csv.gz", transport_params=dict(session=session), encoding="utf-8")
f_out = open("s3://mybucket/2m_sales_records.csv", "w", transport_params=dict(session=session))
byte_count = 0
while True:
    data = f_in.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    f_out.write(data)
    byte_count += len(data)
    print(f"wrote {byte_count} bytes so far")
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

The sample file has **2 million** lines and it's **75 MB** compressed and **238 MB** uncompressed.
I uploaded the compressed file to `mybucket` and ran the code which downloaded the file, extracted the contents in memory and uploaded the uncompressed data back to S3.
On my computer the process took around **78 seconds** (highly dependent on Internet connection speed) and never used more than **95 MB** of memory; I think you can lower the memory requirements if need be by overriding the *part size* for S3 multipart uploads in **smart_open**.

```py
DEFAULT_MIN_PART_SIZE = 50 * 1024**2
"""Default minimum part size for S3 multipart uploads"""
MIN_MIN_PART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 ** 2
"""The absolute minimum permitted by Amazon."""
```

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown? Do you have a sample file to replicate the issue with?

Comment: sorry, figured it - it was binary data